# hiding attributes from inherited_resources rest methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, json, rest

I want to use REST in an Rails application that uses inherited_resources,
but I want certain properties not to be revealed during json and xml request.

Let's call that field 'password'.

I know I can overwrite the to_xml and to_json methods and then

```
super :except => [:password]
```

But I would have to do that for to_xml and to_json. Not very DRY.

Any ideas?

```
rest_member_defaults :except => [:password]
```

in the controller is vaguely what I'm aiming for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact question and yours triggered me to wrap this up into a plugin [hide_attributes](https://github.com/borgand/hide_attributes) which is also available as a gem.

Just add it to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'hide_attributes'
```

And then add something like this to your model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  hide_attributes :password, :password_salt
end
```

And there you go. Sorry that there are no tests yet and documentation is rather thin.